How are we to interpret the differential in the integral?
I have been working a lot with infinitesimals lately and related concepts such as derivatives and integrals. The for a function $y=y(x)$, the differential $\mathrm{d}y$ can be defined to be the change in $y$ for the tangent to the curve $y$, for some change in $x$ $\mathrm{d}x$. So $\mathrm{d}y$ is a function which is dependant on $y(x)$ and $\mathrm{d}x$. This relationship can be expressed as:
$\mathrm{d}y=y'(x)\mathrm{d}x$
When solving differential equations, we often take the integral of both sides and get:
$\displaystyle \int_{}^{}\mathrm{d}y=\int_{}^{}y'(x)\mathrm{d}x$
So using this, it would seem that the integral sign is some sort of operator which takes differentials and "maps them" to their real counterpart. So:
$\displaystyle \int_{}^{}\mathrm{d}y=\int_{}^{}y'(x)\mathrm{d}x \iff y=y(x)$
But this view seems rather vague. I know Leibniz thought about summation of infinitesimally thin rectangles with width $\mathrm{d}x$, but I don't really like that interpretation. Riemann integration is cool and all but it requires limits, which I would like to avoid.
Is there any interpreation of what the integration symbol means that is based on infinitesimals (and preferably not limits)? I find it difficult to square the meaning of $\mathrm{d}y$ as "the change in $y$ for the tangent to the curve $y$" with $\int_{}^{}\mathrm{d}y$.

Have you heard of differential forms? They behave in the way you want: Given a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\  (x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto f(x_1,...,x_n)$, its total differential is given by $$d f = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} d x_i. $$
The fundamental theorem of calculus is then extended to Stoke's theorem, which says that $$\int\limits_{\Omega} d f = \int\limits_{\partial\Omega} f$$ for measurable $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n.$ And of course this whole setup can be extended to manifolds. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form

Or you can go the way of measure theory where, if you permit a metaphor, the expressions $dx$ and $dy$ represent something akin to densities, and calculating an integral corresponds to weighing a region.

@Arthur, I admire the skill with which users around here are able to change the subject when the issue is "infinitesimals" :-)  It doesn't seem to me that you are answering the question.

There seem to be (at least) two separate questions here:

Is $dy$ the corresponding change along the tangent line; and

How does one view integration via infinitesimals?


As far as question 1 is concerned, Leibniz did not see it this way.  For him, $dy$ was the corresponding change along the curve.  This of course runs into difficulties, which Leibniz (thought he) answered by declaring that he is working with a generalized relation of equality (rather than strict equality "on the nose").  This works to a certain extend: if you define a generalized relation of equality $\approx$ by defining $a\approx b$ to mean that $\frac{a}{b}$ is infinitely close to $1$, then some of the machinery of derivatives works.  Thus, if $y=x^2$ then indeed we find $dy\approx 2xdx$ or equivalently $\frac{dy}{dx}\approx 2x$.  However, this can only go this far (and not far enough for modern mathematics).  Instead, one needs to use the standard part (shadow).
As far as question 2 is concerned, there is no doubt about it: what we call the integral and denote $\int$ was a sum to Leibniz.  In fact, he argued against Bernoulli's term "integral" and insisted on "sum" in letters to Bernoulli.  However, he seems to have come around eventually.  From the modern point of view, we define an infinite Riemann sum $S=\sum_a^b f(x)dx$ and then define the integral as the standard part (shadow) of $S$.
So the choice is basically between two options: either use epsilon-delta definitions of limits, or use infinitesimals and standard part (and then limits can be defined in terms of the latter).

When we define integrals using the standard part function of Riemann sums, won't we sometimes undercount a given area? Suppose we try to use an upper sum, and the function is monotonely decreasing. Won't the area we calculated be smaller than the actual area? Or will the discrepancy be infinitesimal, and "disappear" when we use the standard part function? And for the upper bound, do we need to use limits or could we instead use infinities? (if we have infinitesimals, we probably have infinities as well)

Yes, precisely, the discrepancy is infinitesimal (it can be both positive and negative (or zero)).  I am not sure what you mean by your question about "the upper bound".

In regular limit-based calculus, we would typically denote the Riemann sum as: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(x_{k})\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}$. So here, we need a concept of limits. But if we have a number system which includes infinitesimals, we would probably also have infinities. So can we get around limits by using an infinity instead of "n"?

Instead of limit of a Riemann sum as $n$ tends to infinity, one uses a Riemann sum with an infinite (more precisely, unlimited) value of $n$, and then takes the standard part of the "infinite" Riemann sum.  This is a formalisation of Leibniz's idea that an integral should be an infinite sum of infinitely thin rectangles.  Of course, Leibniz did not have the notion of "standard part".

Yes, that is exactly what I was inquiring about. Thank you for the clear and precise explanation! Great answers like always!
